# Looping through an array with PostgreSQL requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am attempting to store the contents of an array in my database.  I want to add a new row for each item in the array. Currently I am running:

```
router.post('/saveVenueMatches', (req, res) => {
  const id = req.body.user_id;
  const data = req.body.data;
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
  for (const venue of data) {
    let sqlText = `INSERT INTO user_matches (user_id, venue_id) VALUES ($1, $2)`;
    pool
      .query(sqlText, [id, venue.id])
      .then((response) => {
        res.send(response.rows);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error saving venue matches', err);
      });
  }
});
```

This results in successful posts to my database, however my server returns the following error once for each item in the array:

```
Error saving venue matches Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
{
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

I have tried removing the line where I set the header but I still get the error.  I am not exactly sure what is causing this.

Additionally if there is a better way to make a request like this please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to send a result to client in each iteration of a cycle but you can do it only once. Try to send results after a cycle or better turn the cycle into `Promise.all` call

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion will be to use multiple insert at once, dont try to hit database too many times.

You can use this npm packages for multiple insert at once

```
const pg = require('pg');
const format = require('pg-format');
```

you need to just format your data accordingly

```
let user_matches = [[1, 2], [2, 3]];
let query1 = format('INSERT INTO users (user_id, venue_id) VALUES %L returning id', user_matches);
let {rows} = await client.query(query);
```

for reference you can visit this website, please
click [here](https://www.wlaurance.com/2018/09/node-postgres-insert-multiple-rows)